# How to pass an intent class to a fragment? Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I want to pass a class to a fragment so I can use it to create and start an intent 
How can i do it?
How can i pass it using bundle and fragment arguments?
Should I pass the intent directly? If so how to handle intents in both activity and fragment lifcycles?

Comment: your question is not clear..  please try re - write it differently.  I really don't think somebody would understand what you want...

Comment: ok I'll do it. Marcin understood my question though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the `class`. You can try with `object` though. On Android, `Parcelable` is the way to go: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

**EDIT**

> Why he cannot pass the class?  An instance of Class class.

Because `class` is a construct, recipe that defines desired set of attributes/properties and methods. It's like recipe - but it you cannot eat recipe. The `object` is your `class` turned into life. Another way to describe the difference I found once is to think of classes as the mold and objects as the items produced using that mold.

And by saying `An instance of Class class` you mean `object`.

Comment: should i use the same intents multiple times?

Comment: Why he cannot pass the class? An instance of `Class` class.

Comment: *"An instance of Class class you mean object"* Nope. I mean an instance of `Class<HisClass>`.